# React warning "export 'GetTheFilteredPosts' was not found in

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to export/import two functions:

```
export function LoadMoreButtonLogic(
  ...
) {
  ...

  return ...
}

export function GetTheFilteredPosts(
  ...
) {
  return (...);
}
```

And importing them this way in another file:

```
import { GetTheFilteredPosts } from '@src/components/commons/load-more-button/LoadMoreButton';
import { LoadMoreButtonLogic } from '@src/components/commons/load-more-button/LoadMoreButton';
```

However I am getting such warnings:

```
warning "export 'GetTheFilteredPosts' was not found in '@src/components/commons/load-more-button/LoadMoreButton'
warning "export 'LoadMoreButtonLogic' was not found in '@src/components/commons/load-more-button/LoadMoreButton'
```

But... if I rename the file `LoadMoreButton.js` to the name of a function exported or I rename the name of the exported function to match the filename, the warning for this function disappears.

`@src` is setup in `jsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
             }
      }
}
```

as well as in gatsby-config:

```
'@src': path.join(__dirname, './src'),
```

And @src is working fine in other components. It is used in tens of places.

If I try the path without `@` I get the same:

```
warning "export 'GetTheFilteredPosts' was not found in '../../../../components/commons/load-more-button/LoadMoreButton'
warning "export 'LoadMoreButtonLogic' was not found in '../../../../components/commons/load-more-button/LoadMoreButton'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Why can't I export them freely?

Comment: Do you have a `@src` namespace setup somehow? If not, that would be the problem. If so, I'm very interested to know how, relative imports get lengthy.

Comment: Yes it's good. I updated the original question

Comment: I've never seen that. I might try that out, its an interesting idea. I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong though. Where does this error originate from? Your text editor, or the compiler?

Comment: I am using VSCode and the code appears in the terminal

Comment: please check this path without `@`

Comment: tried. I updated the original question with the results. It doesn't seem to be related with `@`